# Intellij IDEA riot.js javascript style support

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, riot.js

Is there a way to deal with Intellij IDEA's warnings in riot.js code like the following?

```
// no warnings
function first() {
    return ''
}

// warnings:
// 'expecting new line or semicolon' after '()'
// 'return outside function definition' on return statement
second() {
    return ''
}
```

If I write something like `this.second = function() {}` instead it works fine and there are no warnings. But how can I write beautiful code w/o such warnings?

I couldn't find riot.js plugin for IDEA. Also I tried to turn on ECMAScript 6 in JavaScript settings but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fast-forward a couple of years, there is now a riot.js plugin for IDEA:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12748-riot-js